# How to create json object by repeating a loop in android?

Tags: android, json, shapefile

I want to create Json object by getting points of a shape file in while loop.The shape file contains 73 points.I am storing points of shape file in json oject and adding the object to ArrayList in a loop,below the while loop i m retrieving objects one by one from ArrayList and storing it in JsonArray, but the problem here is  only the last record points of shapefile are storing in the arraylist 73 times.How to solve this problem please help me.

Here is my code

```
try {

        File file= new File(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/ne_50m_admin_0_tiny_countries.shp");
        Long fileLength=file.length();
        Log.d("FileLength is","file"+fileLength);
        String shpFile = Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString()+"/ne_50m_admin_0_tiny_countries.shp";
        //String shpFile = Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString()+"/ne_50m_admin_0_breakaway_disputed_areas.shp";
        ShapeReader reader = new ShapeReader(shpFile, true);
        ShapeType shpType=reader.getHeader().getShapeType();
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject wkidJson = new JSONObject();
        jObject.put("objectIdFieldName","OBJECTID");
        jObject.put("globalIdFieldName","");
        jObject.put("geometryType",shpType);
        wkidJson.put("wkid", new Integer(102100));
        jObject.put("spatialReference",wkidJson);
        JSONArray fieldsList = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject idJson = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject yJson = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject xJson = new JSONObject();
        idJson.put( "name","OBJECTID");
        idJson.put("alias", "OBJECTID");
        idJson.put("type", "esriFieldTypeOID");
        yJson.put( "name","y");
        yJson.put("alias", "y");
        yJson.put("type", "esriFieldTypeDouble");
        xJson.put( "name","x");
        xJson.put("alias", "x");
        xJson.put("type", "esriFieldTypeDouble");
        fieldsList.put(idJson);
        fieldsList.put(yJson);
        fieldsList.put(xJson);
        jObject.put("fields",fieldsList);
        JSONObject geomJson = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject attJson = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject featuresJson = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray featuresList = new JSONArray();
        Log.d("Header info is","Header"+reader.getHeader().getFileLength());
        recordshape=reader.new Record();
        ArrayList a= new ArrayList();
        while (reader.hasNext())
        {

            if(recordshape.end < fileLength)
            {
                if(shpType==ShapeType.POINT)
                {
                    recordshape=reader.nextRecord();
                    int recordNumber=recordshape.number;
                    double Xcoordinate= recordshape.minX;
                    double Ycoordinate=recordshape.minY;
                    Log.d("Xcoordinate info is","Xcoordinate"+Xcoordinate);
                    Log.d("Ycoordinate info is","Ycoordinate"+Ycoordinate);
                    geomJson.put("x", Xcoordinate);
                    geomJson.put("y", Ycoordinate);
                    attJson.put("OBJECTID", recordNumber);
                    attJson.put("y", Ycoordinate);
                    attJson.put("x", Xcoordinate);
                }

            }
            else
                break;

            featuresJson.put("geometry", geomJson);
            featuresJson.put("attributes", attJson);
            a.add(featuresJson);
            Log.d("featuresJson info is","featuresJson"+featuresJson);
         }
        Log.d("featuresJson info is","featuresJson"+featuresJson);
        Log.d("size info is","size"+a.size());
        for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
        {
        featuresList.put(a.get(i));
        }

        Log.d("featuresList info is","featuresList"+featuresList);
        jObject.put("features",featuresList);
        String jsonString = jObject.toString();

        jsonString = jsonString.replace("\\" , "");

        FileWriter writeFile = new FileWriter(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString()+"/Test.json");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(writeFile);
        out.write(jsonString);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("Error","Message"+e.getMessage());
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("Exception","Message"+e.getMessage());
    }
```

The format of json which i want is

```
{
"objectIdFieldName": "OBJECTID",
"globalIdFieldName": "",
"geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint",
"spatialReference": {
    "wkid": 102100
},
"fields": [
    {
        "name": "OBJECTID",
        "alias": "OBJECTID",
        "type": "esriFieldTypeOID"
    },
    {
        "name": "y",
        "alias": "y",
        "type": "esriFieldTypeDouble"
    },
    {
        "name": "x",
        "alias": "x",
        "type": "esriFieldTypeDouble"
    }
],
"features": [
    {
        "geometry": {
            "x": -13021472.272599999,
            "y": 4046325.7190999985
        },
        "attributes": {
            "OBJECTID": 212,
            "y": 4046325.7191,
            "x": -13021472.2726
        }
    },
    {
        "geometry": {
            "x": -13021124.9134,
            "y": 4046747.3976000026
        },
        "attributes": {
            "OBJECTID": 232,
            "y": 4046747.3976,
            "x": -13021124.9134

        }
    }
]
```

}

please help me
Thanks.

Comment: tl;dr. what have you tried, what fails, what errors does that gives you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your loop, you put values in the same json object over and over again. therefore, when you jsonify it, your array contains n*the same object.

You need to create new object to be added in each pass of your loop.

these three declaration must move inside the loop:

```
JSONObject geomJson = new JSONObject();
JSONObject attJson = new JSONObject();
JSONObject featuresJson = new JSONObject();
```